# Multi Threading in Java About start()

Tags: java

When we call the start() method of a thread object, the method automatically calls the run method .how does this mechanism work?

Answer (score 3):

Your question isn't really clear, but `start()` will:

- Start a new thread, whether that's a simulated thread or a "real" OS thread (the latter is more likely these days)
- Make the new thread call `run()`

You can specify the work for the `run()` method *either* by subclassing `Thread`, or (preferably) by passing a `Runnable()` into the `Thread` constructor.

Comment: Is start() have run() calle in start() body

Comment: @VijayKumar: No, because otherwise it would execute `run()` in the *calling* thread, which would defeat the point of `start()`. The implementation doesn't really matter much though - the important thing is the *effect*: `start()` returns, and `run()` is invoked in the new thread.

Answer (score 2):

`start()` is a non-blocking operation, which means it returns immediately. When you call it, it will start a new thread (probably using some operating system native API). This new thread will call `run()`. By that time thread that called `start()` continues to run.

Comment: Is start() have run() calle in start() body

Answer (score 0):

Calling `start` will change the thread's state to Runnable, which doesn't imply that the code inside the `run` method will be called immediately. It only makes a transition to a state where the thread can be eligible to run by the scheduler, which can happen at the very time it is called, or at an undefined point in the future (it is up to the scheduler).

Whether the run method call is made or not is irrelevant (the docs say it is called), but in any case, the first line of code inside `run` is not guaranteed to run immediately, if that's your question.

Think of `start` as a request to the scheduler saying "please run this task when you can".

Comment: Is start() have run() calle in start() body

Comment: No, that happens on the new thread, which is different than the one from where you are calling start.